# Retrieve Coordinates from google maps api

Tags: java, google-maps

I have a list of addresses, i now want to retrieve their longitudes and latitudes. i would like to use the google maps api through java. How would i go about retrieving just one set of co-ords for one address. (cause i could then easily implement for multiple)

Comment: do you want to know the API for this?

Comment: i would like to know how to retrieve the co-ords from the json file returned from a call to the api for a specific address .. i would also like to know how to request the json file itself ..all from within java

Comment: you can go through the link i mentioned in my answer. You can get all the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i did it in the end

```
public static String getCordinates(String address,String county) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException{
    String thisLine;

    address = address.replace(",", "+");
    address = address.replace(" ", "+");
    county = county.replace(" ", "");

    String fullAddress = address+"+"+county;
    System.out.println(fullAddress);

    URL url = new URL("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q="+fullAddress+"&output=xml&key=ABQIAAAANGTAqDyDam_07aWkklK2NBSD41w" +
            "X8VhCBpuiDVjGbFNuXE31lhQB8Gkwy-wmYbmaHIbJtfnlR9I_9A");

    BufferedReader theHTML = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("url.xml");
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    while ((thisLine = theHTML.readLine()) != null)
        out.write(thisLine);
    out.close();

    File file = new File("url.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(file);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("code");
    Element n = (Element)nl.item(0);
    String st = n.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

    if (st.equals("200"))
    {
        NodeList n2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("coordinates");
        Element nn = (Element)n2.item(0);
        String st1 = nn.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();


        return st1;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 5):

You may also use the Google Geocoder Java API [GeoGoogle](http://geo-google.sourceforge.net/) like this:

```
// Initialize a new GeoAddressStandardizer-class with your API-Key
GeoAddressStandardizer st = new GeoAddressStandardizer(apikey);
// Get a list of possible matching addresses
List<GeoAddress> addresses = st.standardizeToGeoAddresses(address);
// Get the first address (like you posted above)
GeoAddress address = addresses.get(0);
// Get the coordinates for the address
GeoCoordinate coords = address.getCoordinate();
// Longitude
double longitude = coords.getLongitude();
// Latitude
double latitude = coords.getLatitude();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [Google API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Comment: how would i go about calling this in java, or is there an example of using this in java?

Comment: you need to make http request from java. Just google out the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Using API with restAssurd is an easy way:

```
 public static String[] getCoordinates(String address, String county) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

    address = address.replace(",", "+");
    address = address.replace(" ", "+");
    county = county.replace(" ", "");

    String fullAddress = address+"+"+county;
    System.out.println(fullAddress);

    URL url = new URL("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+fullAddress+"&sensor=false");

    Response res = given().
            when().
            get(url);
    JsonPath jp = new JsonPath(res.asString());
    String lat = jp.get("results.geometry.location.lat").toString();
    String lng = jp.get("results.geometry.location.lng").toString();

    String[] location = new String[2];
    location[0] = lat;
    location[1] = lng;

    return location;
}
```